# Managing different datatypes in C without code repetition

Tags: c, types

For handling different datatypes the following code does work.  However is there a better way of writing this without repeating the code for different datatypes?

```
in  = (unsigned char *) calloc(pixels, bpp);
out = (unsigned char *) calloc(pixels, bpp);

if (bpp == 1) 
 for (x = 0; x < pixels; x++)
  *(out + (x * bpp)) = *(in + (x * bpp));

if (bpp == 2) 
 for (x = 0; x < pixels; x++)
  *(short *)(out + (x * bpp)) = *(short *)(in + (x * bpp));

if (bpp == 4) 
 for (x = 0; x < pixels; x++)
  *(float *)(out + (x * bpp)) = *(float *)(in + (x * bpp));

if (bpp == 8) 
 for (x = 0; x < pixels; x++)
  *(double *)(out + (x * bpp)) = *(double *)(in + (x * bpp));
```

Thanks for the responses so far and my apologies for my lack of clarity.  The above snippet of code was just an example of what I was trying to achieve. Supposing we want to rearrange the order of values for instance:

```
 for (x = 0; x < pixels; x++)
  *(out + (pixels - 1 - x) * bpp) = *(in + (x * bpp));
```

Here memcpy() would not help.  Basically I want to get rid of the repeated code for the different datatypes, so I can order the values any way I like for any datatype.

Comment: Invoking UB and violating strict aliasing rule is always a bad idea. Note that you should not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: In C, when calling the system function: `calloc()`, 1) the returned value is a `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer. adding a cast just clutters the code and creates major headaches during debugging and/or maintenance.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use `memcpy()`?

```
memcpy(out, in, pixels * bpp);
```